# Font width of non-English fonts

Tags: java, utf-8, fonts, awt, font-size

I am trying to draw characters from Hindi on a plain white background and store the resulting image as a `jpeg`. I need to size the image dynamically so that it fits the text. Currently, image height is fixed by assuming a size of 35 pixels (font size has been set to 22). How do I fix image width?

So far, I have tried to set the image width to 35 pixels times the maximum length of the different lines of text. That has not worked and the images saved are very wide. I am using `drawString` method of the graphics class in Java.

The function that creates images:

```
public static void printImages_temp(List<String> list) {

        /* Function to print translations contained in list to images.
         * Steps:
         * 1. Take plain white image.
         * 2. Write English word on top.
         * 3. Take each translation and print one to each line.
         */

        String dest = tgtDir + "\\" + list.get(0) + ".jpg";  //destination file image.

        int imgWidth_max = 410;
        int imgHeight_max = 230;
        int fontSize = 22;

        Font f = new Font("SERIF", Font.BOLD, fontSize);

        //compute height and width of image.
        int img_height = list.size() * 35 + 20;
        int img_width = 0;
        int max_length = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if(list.get(i).length() > max_length) {
                max_length = list.get(i).length();
            }
        }
        img_width = max_length * 20;

        System.out.println("New dimensions of image = " + img_width + " " + img_height);

        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(img_width, img_height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics g = img.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, img_width, img_height);

        //image has to be written to another file.
        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.setFont(f);
            g.drawString(list.get(i), 10, (i + 1) * 35);            
        }

        //g.drawString(translation, 10, fontWidth); //a 22pt font is approx. 35 pixels long.
        g.dispose();

        try {
            ImageIO.write(img, "jpeg", new File(dest));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("File written successfully to " + dest);
    }
```

My questions:

1. How do I get width of a non-Latin type character, given that the fonts used to render the text are generic?
2. Is there a way to get the width that applies to all UTF-8 characters?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).   This seems an interesting question, and I'd like to play with some possibilities and see if anything I can think of works well for this use-case.

Comment: Andrew, I have added the function that creates images. As you can see, the image height and width are set based on a yardstick that is not very portable. I need a method that could tell me the height and width that each line will occupy so that I can size the image appropriately. The code should be such that it should be portable across languages.

Comment: *"I have added the function that creates images"*  I asked you to post an SSCCE, not a method.  Please *read* the link.